# sendAJAX data parameter in CasperJs

Tags: ajax, casperjs

again, I got another problem with casperjs, now with sendAJAX function.

It says that sendAJAX has 5 parameters which are these followings :

- url: The url to request.
- method: The HTTP method (default: GET).
- data: Request parameters (default: null).
- async: Flag for an asynchroneous request? (default: false)
- settings: Other settings when perform the AJAX request (default:
  null)

So, it says the data method is object so, it should be filled with :

```
var data = new Object();
data.amount= 15;
```

and also with this one,

```
var data = {amount:15};
```

but there were no successful value send to my web service (always send 0 as value, but ajax request successful, even returning the json data) which has an url like this

```
"http://localhost:9000/TempCountryAmountREST/setCountryAmount"
```

It will be succeed if I direct bind my data variable to my url like this :

```
"http://localhost:9000/TempCountryAmountREST/setCountryAmount?amount="+amount
```

[UPDATE]
The TempCountryAmountREST is my controller name and setCountryAmount is my function inside my controller.

[UPDATE]
I forgot to include my usage of sendAJAX(), here is the code that I use :

```
return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, "POST" , data, false, { contentType: "application/json" }));
```

So how does I fill the data in the sendAJAX parameter?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I've found what the answer is.

I make some mistakes in contentType which I was set with contentType: "application/json" instead of contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }

If we are looking about how ajax send the content from method send(), they were use x-www-form-urlencoded. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) for more detail

When we see through casperjs clientutils.js script, we should found how sendAJAX work.
On the `this.sendAJAX = function sendAJAX(url, method, data, async, settings) {
}

there are url construction logic which transformed our Object (if so) to x-www-form-urlencoded form. So that we need to set our `contentType` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Very well, thanks for your attention...